# NEOVIM color scheme and text overlay issue

Tags: shell, neovim

Have color scheme issue when running shell from the Mac, but works once run shell from the VS Code or another IDE.

[Mac Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDwx9.png)

[VS Code Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7D5d.png)

I am using here zsh shell, but from another shells I've got the same issue.

Have someone faced with this?

Answer (score 0):

using the default macOS terminal will not help you since it does not support True Colors natively which is required. VSCode does. You are better off using "Iterm2" as a terminal emulator and all your problems will be gone.